# Converting a C-style string to a C++ std::string

Tags: c++, string, cstring

What is the best way to convert a C-style string to a C++ `std::string`? In the past I've done it using `stringstream`s. Is there a better way?

Comment: What's a cstring? Do you mean a `CString` from MFC? Or a null-terminated array of char (a C string)? Or something else?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

C++ strings have a constructor that lets you construct a `std::string` directly from a C-style string:

```
const char* myStr = "This is a C string!";
std::string myCppString = myStr;
```

Or, alternatively:

```
std::string myCppString = "This is a C string!";
```

As @TrevorHickey notes in the comments, be careful to make sure that the pointer you're initializing the `std::string` with isn't a null pointer. If it is, the above code leads to undefined behavior. Then again, if you have a null pointer, one could argue that you don't even have a string at all. :-)

Comment: and now I also have to do `delete myStr;` no?

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs No, that's not necessary. You only need to delete memory allocated with new. Pointers to string literals don't need to be deallocated.

Comment: I see, so I'm guessing right, string makes an internal copy of this char *.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Yes, though that's independent of whether you need to deallocate the original string.

Comment: Every answer here fails to mention the obvious edge case.  If your char* is NULL, std::string will throw.  It will not be an empty string as many would suspect.  It's unfortunate that all the top posts on stackoverflow don't mention this, and I suspect many people who google for this simple conversion are dealing with the bugs later.

Comment: @TrevorHickey While that's true, one could argue that NULL isn't a string. It's the absence of a string.

Comment: @templatetypedef Agreed.  The answers here aren't wrong, but a disclaimer about NULL would go a long way in terms of helping others.  There are many common functions("getenv()" for example),  that may or may not return NULL when called with the same inputs.  By giving newcomers a simple one-liner without adding a disclaimer is setting them up for failure.

Comment: @templatetypedef Yep, it was precisely a std::string s(getenv(foo)) throwing when the env didn't exist that led me here.    It's sort of clunky that you can't initialize a string to a null value and have the string remain empty.

Comment: a variable that is NULL or nullptr still has a type in statically-typed languages, so I do not think it is correct for std::string to throw or go into undefined behavior when given null. It should ideally initialise empty string.

Answer (score 14):

Check the different constructors of the string class: [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
You maybe interested in:

```
//string(char* s)
std::string str(cstring);
```

And:

```
//string(char* s, size_t n)
std::string str(cstring, len_str);
```

Answer (score 6):

**`C++11`**: Overload a string literal operator

```
std::string operator ""_s(const char * str, std::size_t len) {
    return std::string(str, len);
}

auto s1 = "abc\0\0def";     // C style string
auto s2 = "abc\0\0def"_s;   // C++ style std::string
```

**`C++14`**: Use the operator from `std::string_literals` namespace

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

auto s3 = "abc\0\0def"s;    // is a std::string
```

Answer (score 5):

You can initialise a `std::string` directly from a c-string:

```
std::string s = "i am a c string";
std::string t = std::string("i am one too");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you mean `char*` to `std::string`, you can use the constructor.

```
char* a;
std::string s(a);
```

Or if the `string s` already exist, simply write this:

```
s=std::string(a);
```

Comment: No.  Your example would throw a logic error in std::string's constructor.  'a' cannot be NULL.

Answer (score 2):

In general (without declaring new storage) you can just use the 1-arg constructor to change the c-string into a string rvalue :

```
string xyz = std::string("this is a test") + 
             std::string(" for the next 60 seconds ") + 
             std::string("of the emergency broadcast system.");
```

However, this does not work when constructing the string to pass it by reference to a function (a problem I just ran into), e.g.

```
void ProcessString(std::string& username);
ProcessString(std::string("this is a test"));   // fails
```

You need to make the reference a const reference:

```
void ProcessString(const std::string& username);
ProcessString(std::string("this is a test"));   // works.
```

Answer (score 1):

And yet another way for char arrays now. Similar to `std::vector`'s initialization, at least that's how I remember it.

```
char cBuf[256] = "Hello World";
std::cout << cBuf << '\n';
std::string str{std::begin(cBuf), std::end(cBuf)};
std::cout << str << '\n';
```